# Установщик VisualStudio и реестр

Tags: c#

До этого делал свой установщик для dll библиотек,они вносились в COM и все работало. Прикрутил даже установочник чтобы вносились записи в реестр, необходимые для работы со сборкой. Сейчас делаю все тоже самое, но записи в реестр не заносятся вообще. Хотя все файлы и все остальное вроде как копируется по нужному пути. А в реестре пусто совсем.

Answer (score 0):

Не ту выбрал целевую платформу для установки приложения. Там стояло х32, сделал на х64 и всё стало нормально